# Bootstrap 4 Rating with progress bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4. I want to achieve this:

[image]

Ignore "See All" and "4,327 Ratings"

I ended up only getting this so far:

[image]

Doesn't matter the 5, 4, 3... rating. I can easily replace them with font icons.

Here's my code:

```
 <h4>Ratings and Reviews</h4>
 <div class="d-flex">
   <div class="text-center">
     <span class="display-4 font-weight-bolder">3.1</span><br>
     <span class="text-black-50">out of 5</span>
   </div>
   <div class="flex-grow-1">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-4 text-right">
         5
       </div>
       <div class="col-8">
         <div class="progress" style="height: 2px;">
           <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-4 text-right">
         4
       </div>
       <div class="col-8">
         <div class="progress" style="height: 2px;">
           <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-4 text-right">
         3
       </div>
       <div class="col-8">
         <div class="progress" style="height: 2px;">
           <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-4 text-right">
         2
       </div>
       <div class="col-8">
         <div class="progress" style="height: 2px;">
           <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-4 text-right">
         1
       </div>
       <div class="col-8">
         <div class="progress" style="height: 2px;">
           <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

How do I:
- Make the progress bar vertically middle align with the text/star.
- See that I am using Row/Col, but I'd prefer to use flexbox instead.
- With as minimal CSS as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class `align-items-center` to all `row` elements. By default, rows use `flexbox` in Bootstrap v4

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h4>Ratings and Reviews</h4>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="text-center">
    <span class="display-4 font-weight-bolder">3.1</span><br>
    <span class="text-black-50">out of 5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-4 text-right">
        5
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="progress" style="height: 2px;">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-4 text-right">
        4
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="progress" style="height: 2px;">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-4 text-right">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="progress" style="height: 2px;">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-4 text-right">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="progress" style="height: 2px;">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-4 text-right">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="progress" style="height: 2px;">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```